# Iterating over an array i have created from CSV file

Tags: java

I have read a CSV file into an array by first reading lines of the file in one method and then splitting these lines in another method and was wondering how to iterate through this array in my main in order to access particular values. My code is as follows;

```
public class MainMenu
{   
    public static void readFile(String file)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        InputStreamReader isr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        int lineNum;
        String line;
        try {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while((line != null) && lineNum < 27) {
                lineNum++;
                processLine(line);
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
            }
            
            fileStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(fileStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileStream.close();
                  } catch(IOException ex2) {
                }
            }
             System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void processLine(String csvRow)
    {
        String[] splitLine;
        splitLine = csvRow.split(",");
        int lineLength = splitLine.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(splitLine[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("============================================"+"\n"+"Data from CSV file to be analysed:"+"\n");
        readFile("jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world_ASSIGNMENT-FIXED.csv");
        System.out.println("============================================");
        //want to have code here to iterate through the array and access whichever value necessary
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to return the split arrays in your processLine and readFile methods. For example:

```
public static List<String[]> readFile(String file) {
    // create BufferedReader...
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList();

    while (((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) && lineNum < 27) {
        lineNum++;
        lines.add(processLine(line));
    }

    return lines;
}

public static String[] processLine(String row) {
   String[] splitLine = row.split(",");
   // print line...
   return splitLine;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> lines = readFile("filename.csv");
    // iterate over lines
}
```

Note you could also use a 2D array instead of a list of arrays:

```
public static String[][] readFile(String file) {
    // create reader...
    String[][] lines = new String[27][] // assuming you only want 27 lines

    while (((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) && lineNum < 27) {
        lines[lineNum] = processLine(line));
        lineNum++;
    }

    return lines;
}
```

You should also look into closing your stream in a finally block, or even better: use a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help, is there any chance you could give me an example of how i would use a 2D array instead of the list of arrays, i find it wayyyy easier to work with 2D arrays :)

Comment: @Francois200212 I've added it to the example

Comment: I've actioned all those changes and it doesn't seem to be working, throwing a bunch of invalid method declaration errors

Comment: I noticed I missed the opening bracket for the while block which could be the problem. If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: I am ggetting the error: MainMenu.java:45:         
 error: cannot find symbol
  return lines;
         ^
  symbol:   variable lines
  location: class MainMenu

Comment: But i have done String[][] lines = new String[27][];

Comment: Perhaps your declaration is in a different scope, i.e. inside of the try-block while your return statement is outside of it?